# Share large block device among multiple Kubernetes pods via NFS keeping exports isolated per namespace

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I host multiple projects on a Kubernetes cluster. Disk usage for media files is growing fast. My hosting provider allows me to create large block storage spaces, but these spaces can only be attached to a node (VPS) as a block device. For now I don’t consider switching to an object storage.

I want to use a cheap small VPS with a large block device attached to it as a NFS server for several projects (pods).

I've read some tutorials about using NFS as persistent volumes. The approaches are:

### External NFS service. What about security? How to expose an export to one and only one pod inside the cluster?

ie, on the NFS server machine:

```
/share/
    project1/
    project2/
    ...
    projectN/
```

Where each /share/project{i} must be **only** available to pods in `project{i}` namespace.

### Multiple dockerized NFS services, using the affinity value to attach the nfs services to nfs server node.

I don't know if it's a good practice having many NFS server pods on the same node.

Maybe there are other approaches I'm not aware. What's the best Kubernetes approach for this use case?

Comment: NFS is not suitable for hosting databases, you should look for another storage solution.

Comment: @FL3SH Yes, I know. That's why I did mention "Disk usage for media files". I'm going to edit the question to remove the Nginx/PHP/MariaDB part because it can make some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 1 answer for your questions.
It depends on your solution(architecture),requirements,security many others factors.

- External NFS service. What about security?

In this case all consideration are on your side (my advice is to choose some supported solution by your cloud provided) please refer to [Considerations when choosing a right  solution](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine).

As one example please read about [security NFS Volume Security](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_nfs.html#nfs-volume-security). In your case all responsibility are on administrator side to share volumes and provide appropriate security settings.

- According to the second question.

You can use pv,pvc claim, namespaces and storage classes to achieve your goals.

Please refer to [pv with nfs server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) and [storage classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/)

Note:

> For example, NFS doesn’t provide an internal provisioner, but an external provisioner can be used. Some external provisioners are listed under the repository kubernetes-incubator/external-storage. There are also cases when 3rd party storage vendors provide their own [external provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage) .

For affinity rules please also refer to [Allowed Topologies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#allowed-topologies) in case topology of provisioned volumes will be applied/restricted to  specific zones.

Additional resources:

- [Kubernetes NFS-Client Provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client)
- [NFS Server Provisioner](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/f1e69addab2eb190915fc426f94e1c3024cd2976/stable/nfs-server-provisioner/README.md#nfs-server-provisioner)

Hope this help.